# A problem on Windows 7. Is it a bug?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate. I tried to copy something into my Pendrive. The copying windows will appear. Now, try to click on the small icon on the left of the title bar. A context menu will appear. Click on the icon again. The context menu will disappear but the copying process is also canceled. So, do you have this problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: A friendly remark: If you don't want to get negative feedback you should come with a good question first. Try to look at the current title twice and you'll see that it is not very smart - just improve it.

Answer (score 6):

This does not happen if you click the icon twice slowly, just if you double-click the icon. It is not a bug. Windows lets you double-click the icon to close any window; it is the same as clicking the X in the right corner. As [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/06/08/621757.aspx) explains, back in Windows 3.1, windows were closed by double-clicking the upper-left corner, so Windows allows this for people who were used to it.

In my case, I have never used Windows 3.1, but I sometimes close windows by double-clicking their icon. When the X button is hidden off the right side of the screen, I find it faster to double-click.

Comment: By the way, in the menu, the Close option is bold to remind you double clicking the menu icon will close the window. (Similarly: if you right click on a file or folder icon, the context menu has Open in bold to show that double clicking the icon will open it.)

Comment: I see... I did not realize that even I have used Windows for so many years. Anyway, thanks for your info.